# can i use symfony nodeJS and angular in one application

Tags: node.js, angular, symfony

*hello,* 
*I am doing an audit platform for applications develop in angular node and symfony, my question is that I can use the 3 technology at the same time
here is my project
thank you in advance*

[projet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrcJS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Symfony flex](https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup/flex.html) managing with *composer* your back-end dependencies (pay attention that Symfony flex doesn't come with **Doctrine ORM** by default so you need to require it in your `composer.json` file if you're planning to use a database. If you want to integrate front-end frameworks in your symfony application you need to manage them via `npm` or `yarn`. I do prefer `yarn` since it's more Symfony friendly. The best practice for symfony is using the [webpack](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html) component, check [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) for this. Linked one [demo](https://github.com/mariusbalcytis/symfony-webpack-angular-demo) app for you.